# npm missing script: check

Tags: node.js, gradle, heroku, vaadin

I'm writing my portfolio app and wanted to host it on heroku. I have wrote a simple front end for it (I'm aiming to be a back end developer) in Vaadin 14 and everything works fine when I run it. However when I want to push it to Heroku (or when I do gradlew build on my computer) I'm getting this error:

```
> Task :checkFrontend FAILED
[checkFrontend] Running 'cmd /c "D:\travelfront\node\npm.cmd" run check'
npm ERR! missing script: check
```

I have found something about missing script start, but nothing about check. I'm just learning Java and I have no knowledge about node.js. I guess I have to add something to package.json but I have no idea what. Can you please help me with this?

This is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "no-name",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "dependencies": {
    "@polymer/polymer": "3.2.0",
    "@vaadin/flow-deps": "./target/frontend",
    "@vaadin/vaadin-date-picker": "^4.0.3",
    "@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs": "^2.2.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "compression-webpack-plugin": "3.0.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "5.0.3",
    "raw-loader": "3.0.0",
    "webpack": "4.30.0",
    "webpack-babel-multi-target-plugin": "2.1.0",
    "webpack-cli": "3.3.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "3.3.0",
    "webpack-merge": "4.2.1"
  },
  "vaadinAppPackageHash": "faf3ddfc0109df8dd244a47814c80ef5aa53f8a2e107f5a4ded355bf66697d99"
}
```

Comment: do you have node installed in your windows and it's added to your classpath?

Answer (score 0):

When you deploy on Heroku it usually uses Heroku-18 Stack  https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-18-stack which is based on Ubuntu 18.04

```
> Task :checkFrontend FAILED
[checkFrontend] Running 'cmd /c "D:\travelfront\node\npm.cmd" run check'
npm ERR! missing script: check
```

That code line is not for a Linux machine. It is for Windows. It is located somewhere in your source code.
For your development you might have written some tests. These tests won't run on a Linux machine.